# Laravel - Como pegar, manipular e alterar os itens do LengthAwarePaginator

Tags: php, laravel

Boa noite,

Preciso pegar os dados do banco e fazer uma determinada alteração no retorno usando php antes de retornar os dados.

Não vou colar o exemplo real, pois ele é bem complexo e acabaria atrapalhando o entendimento. Vou criar apenas um exemplo para explicar o que preciso.

Pego os dados do BD usando:

```
$dados = \App\Teste::select('id', 'valor')->paginate();
```

Preciso usar um foreach() para fazer uma determinada alteração. Mas com o paginate() tenho que usar um função para pegar os itens. Diferente do que faria se tivesse usado get()

```
$itens = $dados->getItems();
$novosValores = [];
$novoValor = new \stdClass();
foreach($items as $item){
    $novoValor->id = $item->id
    $novoValor->valor = $item->valor + 1;
    array_push($novosValores, $novoValor);
}
```

Desta forma o array **$novosValores** contém os valores alterados e agora preciso substituir os items de **$dados** por eles. Na documentação da classe não encontrei nenhum método que pudesse fazer isso. Tipo um **setItems()**. Não existe essa função. Mas acredito que deve existir alguma forma. Só não sei qual.

Comment: Não tem mesmo, é um dado de paginação com os dados paginados. Se a alteração for apenas um somatório de 1 no valor se pode fazer isso na própria SQL, o que você pretende!

Comment: Não sei se percebi bem a questão, mas talvez os Mutators resolvam a questão ? Pode manipular e criar atributos a um modelo. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators

Comment: @VirgilioNovic como eu disse antes, este é apenas um exemplo simplificado para explicar minha necessidade. O que preciso fazer vai muito além de apenas somar +1 e como não consegui resolver com sql estou manipulando os dados com php.

Comment: Então fica complicado eu dar uma opinião correta pra você sobre isso, @BrunoPassos, você poderia explicar um pouco sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver criando um novo objeto de LengthAwarePaginator e colocando nele os dados que foram alterados.

Encontrei o exemplo em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37102841/laravel-change-pagination-data

Segue a abaixo como ficaria para o meu exemplo:

```
$novosDados = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator(
                $novosValores,
                $dados->total(),
                $dados->perPage(),
                $dados->currentPage(), [
                    'path' => \Request::url(),
                    'query' => [
                        'page' => $dados->currentPage()
                    ]
                ]
            );
```